# "Prepare" Vs "Get / Make ready"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

As you know the two verbs ["prepare"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/prepare) and ["make/get ready"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/ready) are two completely similar verbs and have lots of semantic overlaps in usage. Aside from some broader usages of the verb "prepare", the only main thing that distinguishes these two verbs from one another is that the verb "prepare" is a little more formal than "make/get ready".

In order to define that, I will provide you with some examples. I wonder if you could let me know which word is suited to which sentence and which word doesn't and why?

### Examples:

> 1. We know all the possible consequences of the matter, and we have already ........... for bad news.

a. prepared ourselves 
b. made ourselves ready 
c. gotten ourselves ready

> 2. Wait, please! Can you give me some time to ............. — No, we're running out of time. We've got to go; now!

a. prepare myself? 
b. make myself ready? 
c. get myself ready?

> 3. Don't worry! This course will ............ for the exam.

a. prepare you 
b. make you ready 
c. get you ready

> 4. The coach is ............. for the upcoming competitions.

a. preparing his team 
b. making his team ready 
c. getting his team ready

**P.S.** I have already seen the similar threads on the forum.

Comment: See also: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36747/im-ready-for-something-vs-im-prepared-for-something

Comment: I would say 1A without *ourselves*, 2C without *myself*, 3A and 4A. Because it simply sounds better to my ear, I'll just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Agree with @krobelusmeetsyndra, but I'd also say 4C is equally natural.

Comment: Thank you very much @krobelusmeetsyndra  and jimbobmcgee, but I lack your intuituons as you seem to be native speakers. So, I need to know how shall I diagnose where to use each one?