# Is the sentence "this raises a question in my mind whether ..." grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I [suggested an edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/36747/109190) a few hours ago, which is approved.

> this raises a question in my mind, **that is**, whether "I'm ready for something" is equal to "I'm prepared for something"

and then another contributor removed the "**that is**", as a result we have

> this raises a question in my mind whether ...

Is it grammatical? What is the structure of it.

"this" functions as a subject; "raises" functions as a predicate; "a question" functions as an object; "in my mind" is an adverbial phrase.

With "that is", the rest is a relative clause; without "that is", what is the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit is correct and uncomplicates the indirect question as originally written by deleting "that is".  Without "that is", the rest of the indirect question is a noun clause.

**Whether** is a conjunction and is similar to **if.**  It is both formal and common to use the subordinate conjunction "whether" to introduce clauses after verbs of asking.

Comment: Thank you. Is my first example, the one with "that is", an indirect question?

Comment: Yes.  It is implied as "whether or not" the following two options in quotations are equal to one another. By the way, they are not since they do not mean the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it also a relative clause, right?

Comment: Yes, in the original construction with "that is," it is a relative clause since it asserts something; however, it still is an indirect question.

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you. Actually, I use "whether" a lot, e.g. ["I am not sure whether I used the right tense"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240481/109190), is that also an indirect question?

Comment: Yes.  To determine this, try to put the part that you think is the indirect question part into the form of a direct question.  If it works, then it is an indirect question.  "Have I used the right tense?"

Comment: Thanks for your patience! You are really a nice answer! Based on the discussion above, is it reasonable to conclude that most of the convert relative clauses could be converted to noun clause?

Comment: Yes, if they meet the criteria to be a noun clause.  Indirect questions are usually noun clauses. They may be used in various noun constructions….(1) as object of some verb of asking or the like; (2) as subject; (3) as predicate nominative; (4) as appositive; (5) as object of a preposition.

Comment: Sorry for typo. I meant to say "You are really a nice answerer!" I guess I've got the rules about the conversion. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you!  I hope this has been of help for you.